# Avoid multiple definition due to inclusion of same header file in case of multiple compilation units

Tags: c, header-files, multiple-definition-error

I have a frequently used function `f()`. I want `f()` to be in header file `util.h`, so that I can use `f()` easily without any extra compilation:

`user1.c`:

```
#include "util.h"
int main(){
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

`util.h`:

```
void f(){
    // do some job
}
```

Compilation of `user1.c`:

```
gcc -o user1 user1.c
```

The problem occurs when there are two compilation units `unit2.o` and `unit3.o`. Their source codes are as follows:

`user2.c`:

```
#include "util.h"

void user2_function(){
     f();
     // do other jobs
}
```

`user3.c`:

```
#include "util.h"
extern void user2_function();
int main(){
    f();
    user2_function();
    return 0;
}
```

I get `multiple definition of f` error when I try to compile these source codes as follows:

```
gcc -c user2.c
gcc -c user3.c
gcc -o user user2.o user3.o
```

Question is how the `multiple definition` problem can be solved? Or are there any better solutions?

In the real case, there are hundreds of functions in `util.h` and there are about 50 different compilation units.

I am trying to avoid using a library and the compilation step of utility functions since:

1. There are many different platforms that I use.
2. I wonder if there is a simple solution, i.e., without using `cmake`, etc.
3. I also use cross compilation for coprocessors.
4. I want the flags used in compilation of the utility functions to be same as the flags used in compilation of user codes.

Comment: If you want to use it in multiple files, either make it static in the header or declare it in the header and define it in its own source file.  Trying to use the non-static function definition from the header is … not going to work well.  As you've found out, the hard way.  There's a reason why functions such as `printf()` are not defined in `<stdio.h>`; this is it!

Comment: Are there any reverse effects of using `static` or `static inline` in terms of runtime performance, TLB miss count, instruction cache miss count, etc.? Compilation time is not important for me.

Comment: If it is static, then each file that includes the header gets a copy of the function, whether it is used or not, so the program ends up with multiple copies of the code for the function. If you use `static inline`, the code only gets generated if you use it. There's wasted space, therefore, and the fact that if it is used a lot, you might end up needing multiple copies of the same code in memory, one for each file that it is called from, which increases the probability of instruction cache misses. Adding one extra object file to a program using several is easy. Use a library to make it easier.

Answer (score 7):

You are actually specifying the body of the function in the header file.  Therefore object code will be emitted for it into both object files, which is not allowed/valid.

To rectify this either:

- Mark the function `inline`
- Place only a forward declaration of the function in the header file, and specify the body in a separate source code file, which you then compile along with your other source code files

Comment: I try to avoid `you then compile along with your other source code files`. I need a *simple* solution since there are lots of platforms, cross compilation, flag consistency, ...

Comment: Declaring the function `static` would also work, yes, although it would have a different meaning/effect.  The `static` function would actually have its body emitted in both translation units, but the compiler/linker would use magic so that there wouldn't actually be two definitions.  I.e. you would have two copies of the function.  In the case of `inline` the function is emitted into both translation units, but the linker then removes one of the definitions.  I.e. you would have only one copy of the function.

Comment: Defining the function as a `static` function in the header would work, but would replicate the code in each object file that used the header.  Further, if a file needed the header but not the function, the function would still be defined (but unused, possibly leading to compiler warnings).  A `static inline` function definition might work better, if the function is small enough for `inline` to be a sensible option — though the compiler simply won't inline it if it is not sensible.

Comment: Declaring a function `inline` has nothing to do with its size.  You are not overriding the compiler's inlining logic.  The `inline` keyword means something entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

Change `util.h` to be `util.c`

And use a new `util.h` that contains

```
void f();
```

instead.